# Long time to boot -180 seconds-

Tags: boot, startup

could you help with my boot time. I´ve tried some solutions with no results, including:

- nomodeset as grub boot option
- kernel upgrade to 2.6.39

Here´s the image of bootchart https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps1E4.png

And here´s the dmesg & lsmod | grep tpm -at the end- output http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38927870/dmesg%20output.txt

On Ubuntu 11.04 , Kernel 2.6.38-12-generic, Graphic card: Nvidia GeForce 8400M GS

Thanks in advance

Comment: if the answer does not work for you - please add the results of `lsmod | grep tpm` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your system is trying to load the driver for Trusted Platform Module chips but its not being able to do so. I am not sure about your current hardware, because there is no information on your question, but you can try to blacklist that module (its not loading anyways).

Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (`sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` or similar using your fav text editor) and add the line `blacklist tpm_tis`.

Reboot.

Comment: Hi @brunopereira81 I´ve tried add the line to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf with no results, stills hanging up the same time. Thanks

Comment: Please follow foosfreedom advice, paste it to the question.

Comment: I´ve add the **lsmod | grep tpm** to http://dl.dropbox.com/u/38927870/dmesg%20output.txt it´s at the end of the text, is just that i can´t add more than two url. Thanks