# Ubuntu taking very long time to boot

Tags: 12.10, boot

So I've insalled Ubuntu 12.10 from a usb stick alongside with Windows. When I boot Ubuntu, it spends about 10 minutes in a purple screen, no cursor, no nothing, then it goes to a black screen but with a cursor, and lastly the login screen, which stays frozen for like 10 minutes. After I login, the screen stays frozen on an empty wallpaper for 10 minutes aswell. Finally after Ubuntu boots, everything runs ultra slowly. Firefox takes a few minutes to launch and freezes every like 10 seconds.
Ive got an Intel Pentium 2.93 Ghz dual core processor, 4 Gigs of ram, Geforce GTS250.

Comment: Open a terminal and write `$ gksu gedit /etc/default/grub` Remove splash and quiet from GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. Then reboot, you should get some more information.

Comment: Run the command `dmesg > ~/dmesg.txt` and post the contents of the file dmesg.txt in your home directory. This will show what is happening during boot.

Comment: @tgies Heres the dmesg.txt [Pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/kwceds7T)

Comment: Ubuntu seems to have some issues with file systems and a usb-device. Does disconnecting all USB devices make it boot faster?

Comment: @Fred. Thank you! I've posted an answer below that explains how to read `dmesg` output, as well as a probable solution to your specific output.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/74918/long-time-to-boot-180-seconds

Answer (score 7):

The first step in diagnosing a slow boot is to look at the output of `dmesg`. `dmesg` displays the contents of the kernel ring buffer, which contains status messages logged by the kernel more or less from the moment control is passed to the Linux kernel to the point that your syslog daemon takes over those logging duties.

To get the output of dmesg in a file for easy browsing, do `dmesg > dmesg.txt`. Now `dmesg.txt` in your current directory contains the kernel log.

**Reading dmesg:** Every line of dmesg output starts with a sequence like `[    0.106607]`. This is a timestamp in "T-plus" format: it is the number of seconds since the instant the kernel started.

To identify your slowdown, look for a point where the timestamp "jumps" a great deal from one line to the next (hint: you can also use `dmesg -d` to get dmesg to print the time difference from one timestamp to the next in angle brackets after the timestamp):

```
[    3.201806] usb 2-4: >New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[    3.201810] usb 2-4: >Product: Android
[    3.201813] usb 2-4: >Manufacturer: Android
[    3.201816] usb 2-4: >SerialNumber: 00093f054d0a2f
[   43.254818] EXT4-fs (sda5): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[   43.254827] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 10747985
[   43.254879] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 10748275
[   43.254892] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 10748394
```

Here we see a jump from T+3 seconds to T+43 seconds, meaning that for 40 seconds the kernel was logging nothing, and presumably twiddling its thumbs waiting for something to happen. This is right after it's recognized an Android device plugged in, so for starters, we might want to try having that Android device unplugged during boot. That could be a red herring, though -- the delay might be incurred by the filesystem cleanup that is happening next.

This is followed shortly by:

```
[   43.254959] EXT4-fs (sda5): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 10748175
[   43.254969] EXT4-fs (sda5): 8 orphan inodes deleted
[   43.254970] EXT4-fs (sda5): recovery complete
[   52.161162] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  451.530476] Adding 51097596k swap on /dev/sda2.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:51097596k
[  451.540572] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  455.117113] udevd[430]: starting version 175
[  458.734692] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
```

Wow, a gap from T+52 seconds to T+451 seconds. We notice that the last thing that happens prior to the delay is the filesystem being mounted.

A little research (doing a Google search for 'slow boot dmesg "mounted filesystem with ordered data mode"') yields a promising lead: [an unfixed bug pertaining to `udev`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/906358) that refers to a long wait at boot right after this message!

Browsing that thread, it looks like a [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udev/+bug/906358/comments/31) has been established:

> It consists in adding a --noudevsync parameter to the vgchange command in /lib/udev/rules.d/85-lvm2.rules. Then regenerating the initramfs with update-initramfs -u

So we'll do something like this:

`sudo nano /lib/udev/rules.d/85-lvm2.rules`

Find the excerpt that looks like `/sbin/lvm vgchange -a y` and change it to read `/sbin/lvm vgchange --noudevsync -a y`. It may be necessary to append the same option to the `/sbin/lvm vgscan` call.

Now do `sudo update-initramfs -u` and reboot when it is successful.

Comment: Use the `profile` parameter on boot too? http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2012/01/how-to-increasespeed-up-ubuntu-booting.html

Comment: @FrederikSpang That's not really going to fix this problem (and in any case that blog is giving bad advice -- you shouldn't make `profile` a permanent fixture of your kernel command line unless you'd like it to boot far slower; just hit e at GRUB, append `profile` to the kernel command line after `quiet splash`, and hit Ctrl-x.

Comment: The article states, to profile it once, and then remove the parameter again.

Comment: The file /lib/udev/rules.d/85-lvm2.rules doesn't exist. What should I do at this point? I'm using Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: Why are you searching for the log file _above_ the big jump? Isn't the message _below_ it the one that took so long? After all, it says "mount**ed** filesystem [..]" ...